# VBA - "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" - Cells()

Tags: vba, excel

Following a tutorial for arrays on VBA Excel. As you can see, just about everything is commented out and I still get this error. If I use **Range("A1", "A1").Value = 1** there's no problem. I also noticed that the intelisense doesn't pick up 'Cells('

```
Option Explicit

Sub ArrayTest()

'Dim arrayint(1 To 5) As Integer
'Dim i As Integer
'Dim j As Integer


'    For j = 1 To UBound(arrayint)
'        arrayint(j) = 10 * j
'    Next j

'    For i = i To UBound(arrayint)
        Cells(1, 1).Value = 1 'arrayint(i)
'    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Where did you put this code (sheet, workbook, module, ...)?

Comment: Excel 2013. I tried it in sheet, workbook and module. I also tried it in a new excel and still nothing...

Comment: Try using `Application` then check if `Intellisense` pick up `Cells` property. So, in short, try this `Application.Cells(1, 1).Value = 1`. I have no way to test it at XL 2013, so give it a try.

Comment: @L42: Thanks !!! It all works now :D Is there a way to not have to use 'Application.' ? Update your answer and I'll mark it the best.

Comment: Well, basically it should work without explicitly using `Application`. I have no problem in it at XL 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Application` and check if `Intellisense` picks up `Cells` property.
If so, replace your code by this:

```
Application.Cells(1, 1).Value = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not commented the line

```
Cells(1, 1).Value = 1 'arrayint(i)
```

This may be the reason for error.